# Call an API from angularjs with promise (async - false)on browser close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, api

I want to call a server side API but the problem is even before API call is made browser gets closed.

```js
$(window).on('beforeunload ', function() {
  var date = Date.now();
  var params = {
    "accountid": localStorageService.get('accountid'),
    "refreshtoken": localStorageService.get('refreshtoken'),
    "date": date
  };
  accountSvc.browserClose(params).$promise
    .then(function(response) {

    }).catch(function(er) {
      console.log(er);
    });

});
```

Comment: what errors did you encounter?

Comment: You cannot use promises on close. You need to do sync calls.

Comment: Since your call is async the browser will close the page before your async operation can complete. I'm not sure if this is a good idéa, but I'll watch this with interest...

Comment: @guest271314 calling the server on close of the browser. Fairly clear description

Comment: there is no error , browser just gets closed. can anyone tell me how to do sync calls @mplungjan

Comment: Look in the duplicate I gave you